# Прерывистая рамка посередине css

Tags: html, css

Ребята, не знаю как реализовать данную рамку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думала воспользоватся before, after, но мудрила и ничего не вышло. подскажите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант если фон всего блока просто цвет:

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

section {
  background: #fff;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #f9cf1d;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.box {
  border: 5px solid #f9cf1d;
  padding: 1rem;
  min-height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px;
  background: #fff;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:50px;
  color: skyblue;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}

.left {
  left: -25px;
}

.right {
  right: -25px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  
<section>
  <div class="box">
    <a href="#" class="left"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href="#" class="right"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    
    <h1> Hello, World</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

Вариант если фон задан не монотонный:

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

section {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1525286944502-268e726aece1?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=e5072792ce04efef19c40a9b54cd3503&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.box {
  border-top: 5px solid #f9cf1d;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #f9cf1d;
  padding: 1rem;
  min-height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:50px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 48px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
  left: -24px;
  text-align: left;
}

.right {
  right: -24px;
  text-align: right;
}

a>span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}

.left>span>i {
  margin-left: 16px;
}

.right>span>i {
  margin-right: 16px;
}

a>span:before,
a>span:after {
  content: '';
  width: 5px;
  background: #f9cf1d;
  
  position: absolute;
}

a.left>span:before,
a.left>span:after {
  left: 24px;
}

a.right>span:before,
a.right>span:after {
  right: 24px;
}

a>span:before {
  top: -9999px;
  bottom: 100%;
}

a>span:after {
  top: 100%;
  bottom: -9999px;;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  
<section>
  <div class="box">
    <a href="#" class="left"><span><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
    <a href="#" class="right"><span><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
    
    <h1> Hello, World! </h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

p.s: Есть еще варианты с svg.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так. Задаете блоку со стрелками высоту и ширину, которая смогла бы покрыть эту прерывность в рамке и также задаете белый фон. А сами стрелки добавляете через **background: url('');** и через **background-position;** позиционируете их.

Answer (score 1):

Можно менять динамически высоту

```css
.block:before,
.block:after{
  content:  '<';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  background: white;
  left: -5px;
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}

.block:after{
  left: 100%;
  content:  '>';
}

.block{
  border: 5px solid green;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  margin:  50px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```